# Interactive auction board

Tags: vb.net

An exam requires me to  create a program for an interactive board for an auction:

> An auction company has an interactive auction board at their sale rooms, which allows buyers to place bids at any time during the
> auction. Before the auction starts, the sellers place their items in
> the sale room with a unique number attached to each item (item
> number). The following details about each item need to be set up on
> the interactive auction board system: item number, number of bids,
> description and reserve price. The number of bids is initially set to
> zero. During the auction, buyers can look at the items in the sale
> room and then place a bid on the interactive auction board at the sale
> room. Each buyer is given a unique number for identification (buyer
> number). All the buyer needs to do is enter their buyer number, the
> item number and their bid. Their bid must be greater than any existing
> bids. At the end of the auction, the company checks all the items and
> marks those that have bids greater than the reserve as sold. Any items
> sold will incur a fee of 10% of the final bid to be paid to the
> auction company. Write and test a program or programs for the auction
> company.
>
> - Your program or programs must include appropriate prompts
>   for the entry of data, data must be validated on entry.
> - Error
>   messages and other output need to be set out clearly and
>   understandably.
> - All variables, constants and other identifiers must
>   have meaningful names.
>
> You will need to complete these three tasks.
> Each task must be fully tested.
>
> #### Task 1 – Auction set up.
>
> For every
> item in the auction the item number, description and the reserve price
> should be recorded. The number of bids is set to zero. There must be
> at least 10 items in the auction.
>
> #### Task 2 – Buyer bids.
>
> A buyer should
> be able to find an item and view the item number, description and the
> current highest bid. A buyer can then enter their buyer number and
> bid, which must be higher than any previously recorded bids. Every
> time a new bid is recorded the number of bids for that item is
> increased by one. Buyers can bid for an item many times and they can
> bid for many items.
>
> #### Task 3 – At the end of the auction.
>
> Using the
> results from TASK 2, identify items that have reached their reserve
> price, mark them as sold, calculate 10% of the final bid as the
> auction company fee and add this to the total fee for all sold items.
> Display this total fee. Display the item number and final bid for all
> the items with bids that have not reached their reserve price. Display
> the item number of any items that have received no bids. Display the
> number of items sold, the number of items that did not meet the
> reserve price and the number of items with no bids.

Here's my solution in VB.net console.  How could I have done it better?

```
'Task 1'
Dim enteries, d As Integer
d = 1

Console.WriteLine("How many total entries?")
enteries = Console.ReadLine
While enteries < 10
    Console.WriteLine("Number of enteries should be greater than 10, please try again")
    enteries = Console.ReadLine
End While
Dim item_num(enteries), num_bids(enteries) As Integer
Dim reserve_price(enteries) As Single
Dim description(enteries) As String
For c = 1 To enteries
    Console.WriteLine("Enter item description")
    description(c) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the item number")
    item_num(c) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter reserve price") 'The reserve price is the minimum amount the seller is willing to accept' 
    reserve_price(c) = Console.ReadLine
    num_bids(c) = 0
Next
For c = 1 To enteries
    For d = 1 To enteries - 1
        If item_num(d) = item_num(d + 1) Then
            While item_num(d) = item_num(d + 1)
                Console.Write("Value " & d + 1)
                Console.WriteLine(" Is duplicate, enter a new value")
                item_num(d + 1) = Console.ReadLine
            End While
        End If
    Next
Next
'Task 2'
Dim buyer_num(enteries) As Integer
Dim bid(enteries), highest(enteries) As Single
Dim extra_bids As String
For c = 1 To enteries
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of the item from 1-" & enteries)
    d = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Product is: " & description(d))
    Console.WriteLine("Item number is: " & item_num(d))
    Console.WriteLine("Current highest bid: " & bid(d))
    Console.WriteLine("Enter buyer number")
    buyer_num(d) = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your bid")
    bid(d) = Console.ReadLine
    If bid(d) > highest(d) Then
        highest(d) = bid(d)
    End If
    num_bids(d) = num_bids(d) + 1
    Console.WriteLine("Make more bids? Enter Yes/No")
    extra_bids = Console.ReadLine
    While extra_bids = "Yes"
        Console.WriteLine("Current highest bid is " & highest(c))
        Console.WriteLine("Enter bid")
        bid(d) = Console.ReadLine
        If bid(d) > highest(d) Then
            highest(d) = bid(d)
        Else
            While bid(d) < highest(d)
                Console.WriteLine("Bid cannot be less than the previous bid, please enter a higher value")
                bid(d) = Console.ReadLine
            End While
            highest(d) = bid(d)
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Make more bids? Enter Yes/No")
        extra_bids = Console.ReadLine
    End While
Next
'Task 3'
Dim final_price(enteries), comp_fee(enteries), total_fee As Single
Dim items_sold, not_sold, no_bids As Integer
Dim sold_status(enteries) As String
For c = 1 To enteries
    If highest(c) >= reserve_price(c) Then
        sold_status(enteries) = "Sold"
        comp_fee(c) = 10 / 100 * highest(c)
        final_price(c) = highest(c) + comp_fee(c)
        total_fee = total_fee + final_price(c)
        items_sold = items_sold + 1

    Else
        not_sold = not_sold + 1
        Console.WriteLine(item_num(c) & " Did not reach reserve price")
        Console.WriteLine("Their final bid was " & highest(c))
    End If
    If num_bids(c) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine(item_num(c) & "recieved no bids")
        no_bids = no_bids + 1
    End If
Next
Console.WriteLine("Total fee for all sold items is " & total_fee)
Console.WriteLine("Number of items sold = " & items_sold)
Console.WriteLine("Number of items not sold = " & not_sold)
Console.WriteLine("Number of items with no bids = " & no_bids)
Console.ReadKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I'll admit I am a little bit rusty right now on some best practices, but I'm doing this anyway.

First, this whole thing needs to be wrapped in a `sub` I assume.

Second, when I read the description of what you need to create, it screams at me "**objects!**" - what I mean is that you have an interactive app that needs to keep track of auction items. Each item has several attributes. Sounds like the basis for some *object-oriented design* doesn't it? e.g.

```
Public Class AuctionItem
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property reservePrice As Integer
    Public Property numberOfBids As Integer
    Public Property currentBid As Integer
    Public Property currentBidder As Integer
End Class
```

So right out of the gate, now you have a structure for the items at the auction, before doing anything else. And each item has properties. And now you just handle a list of the room you're talking about

```
Dim firstRoom As New List(Of AuctionItem)
```

Ignoring the minimum entry requirement, you could simply create your auction on the fly -

```
    Dim firstRoom As New List(Of AuctionItem)
    Dim numberOfEntries As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("How many total entries?")
    numberOfEntries = Console.ReadLine
    For i As Integer = 1 To numberOfEntries
        firstRoom.Add(New AuctionItem)
        Console.WriteLine("Enter item description")
        firstRoom(i).description = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Enter reserve price") 'The reserve price is the minimum amount the seller is willing to accept' 
        firstRoom(i).reservePrice = Console.ReadLine
    Next
```

See what I mean? Now **you** assign the item number and when a bidder wants to bid on it, you just access that object and get what you need.

Another small thing I noted is that you aren't type checking entries - say I want to say my item number is "two" - the program throws an unhandled error and crashes. You expect an integer, so you need to check you receive an integer.

Sorry, that's all I got right now.